# How to split images without errors?

Tags: python-3.x

First of all, apologize for my English.

I have a python code that slices images stored in a google drive folder into multiple predefined parts by coordinates if it meets a certain image color condition. Once sectioned and passed to grayscale, it stores them in another google drive folder. Apparently it works correctly, because it sections the images perfectly so that you can then view them with any image viewing or editing program.
The thing is that I then convert these images to google docs to be able to extract the text from each image and this is where the problem comes, the vast majority of the images recognize them well and extract the text, with better or worse success , but there are some that are not recognized by google docs. Be careful, when I say that it does not recognize them, I am not saying that the text that it extracts is blank, but rather that it does not recognize the image file. I say this, because when you open an image in google docs, it generates a document headed by the image and below it adds the text extracted from it. When it doesn't recognize the image, it generates a totally blank doc, without the image header, which at least should be.
I have tried raising the resolution, as you will see in the code, but I have not been able to improve the result. In the end, it always generates a small group of images that Google docs doesn't end up recognizing.
To give more information, say that the original images that I section are jpg images of mobile screenshots. That in total ends up sectioning about 100 images at most at once.
Below I leave the code to see if someone can help me solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
def get_dominant_colors(image):
    """
    Retorna los 3 colores predominantes de una imagen
    """
    pixels = image.getcolors(image.size[0] * image.size[1])
    sorted_pixels = sorted(pixels, key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=True)
    return [color[1] for color in sorted_pixels[:10]]

def is_color_in_range(color, range1, range2):
    """
    Retorna True si el color se encuentra en un rango de tonos que incluya range1 y range2
    """
    r, g, b = color
    return ((r >= range1[0] and r <= range2[0]) and
            (g >= range1[1] and g <= range2[1]) and
            (b >= range1[2] and b <= range2[2]) and
            color != (255, 255, 255))

def divide_imagenes3(creds, origen_id, destino_id, nombre_equipo):
    coordenadas_2400 = [(810, 300, 1100, 390), (810, 385, 1100, 475), (810, 470, 1100, 560), (810, 555, 1100, 645), (810, 635, 1100, 730), (810, 720, 1100, 810), (810, 810, 1100, 890)]
    coordenadas_2400_2 = [(1340, 300, 1490, 390), (1340, 385, 1490, 475), (1340, 470, 1490, 560), (1340, 555, 1490, 645), (1340, 635, 1490, 730), (1340, 720, 1490, 810), (1340, 810, 1490, 890)]
    coordenadas_4800 = [(1620, 600, 2200, 780), (1620, 770, 2200, 950), (1620, 940, 2200, 1120), (1620, 1110, 2200, 1290), (1620, 1270, 2200, 1460), (1620, 1440, 2200, 1620), (1620, 1620, 2200, 1780)]
    coordenadas_4800_2 = [(2680, 600, 2980, 780), (2680, 770, 2980, 950), (2680, 940, 2980, 1120), (2680, 1110, 2980, 1290), (2680, 1270, 2980, 1460), (2680, 1440, 2980, 1620), (2680, 1620, 2980, 1780)]
    coordenadas_7200 = [(2430, 900, 3300, 1170), (2430, 1155, 3300, 1425), (2430, 1410, 3300, 1680), (2430, 1665, 3300, 1935), (2430, 1905, 3300, 2190), (2430, 2160, 3300, 2430), (2430, 2430, 3300, 2670)]
    coordenadas_7200_2 = [(4020, 900, 4470, 1170), (4020, 1155, 4470, 1425), (4020, 1410, 4470, 1680), (4020, 1665, 4470, 1935), (4020, 1905, 4470, 2190), (4020, 2160, 4470, 2430), (4020, 2430, 4470, 2670)]
    coordenadas_9600 = [(3240, 1200, 4400, 1560), (3240, 1540, 4400, 1900), (3240, 1880, 4400, 2240), (3240, 2220, 4400, 2580), (3240, 2540, 4400, 2920), (3240, 2880, 4400, 3240), (3240, 3240, 4400, 3560)]
    coordenadas_9600_2 = [(5360, 1200, 5960, 1560), (5360, 1540, 5960, 1900), (5360, 1880, 5960, 2240), (5360, 2220, 5960, 2580), (5360, 2540, 5960, 2920), (5360, 2880, 5960, 3240), (5360, 3240, 5960, 3560)]
    ocre_range = ((120, 120, 70), (200, 200, 120))
    amarillo_range = ((200, 200, 115), (245, 245, 200))
    ama_range = ((190, 190, 115), (225, 230, 140))
    blanco_range = ((246, 246, 246), (255, 255, 255))
    temp_file_path = None  # Inicializamos la variable con None

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        query = f"'{origen_id}' in parents"
        results = service.files().list(q=query, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        for n, item in enumerate(items):
            if not item['name'].lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg')):
                continue
            if item['name'] == '666.jpg':
                continue
            file_id = item['id']
            file_name = item['name']
            response = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id).execute()
            image_bytes = io.BytesIO(response)
            image = Image.open(image_bytes)

            if image.size == (2400, 1080) and nombre_equipo == 'UNIÓN~H1':
                coordenadas = coordenadas_2400
                coordenadas2 = coordenadas_2400_2
            elif image.size == (4800, 2160) and nombre_equipo == 'UNIÓN~H1':
                coordenadas = coordenadas_4800
                coordenadas2 = coordenadas_4800_2
            elif image.size == (7200, 3240) and nombre_equipo == 'UNIÓN~H1':
                coordenadas = coordenadas_7200
                coordenadas2 = coordenadas_7200_2
            elif image.size == (9600, 4320) and nombre_equipo == 'UNIÓN~H1':
                coordenadas = coordenadas_9600
                coordenadas2 = coordenadas_9600_2
            else:
                continue

            time.sleep(2)

            image = Image.open(image_bytes)
            for i in range(7):
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordenadas[i]
                part = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))

                colors = get_dominant_colors(part)
                is_color_in_range_flag = False
                for color in colors:
                    if (is_color_in_range(color, ocre_range[0], ocre_range[1]) or is_color_in_range(color, amarillo_range[0], amarillo_range[1]) or is_color_in_range(color, ama_range[0], ama_range[1])) and color != (255, 255, 255):
                        is_color_in_range_flag = True
                        break

                if is_color_in_range_flag:
                    part = part.convert('L')

                    temp_file_path = f'{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg'
                    with open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as f:
                        part.save(f, format='JPEG', quality=100, optimize=True, resolution=300)

                    with Image.open(temp_file_path) as temp_image:
                        enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(temp_image)
                        temp_image = enhancer.enhance(1.5)
                        temp_image.save(temp_file_path, quality=100, optimize=True, resolution=300)

                    new_file_name = f'{n+1}.{i+1}.png'
                    file_metadata = {'name': new_file_name, 'parents': [destino_id]}
                    with open(temp_file_path, 'rb') as f:
                        media = googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(f.read()), mimetype='image/png', chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)

                    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

                    image = Image.open(image_bytes)
                    for j in range(len(coordenadas2)):
                        if j == i:  # comprobamos si seccionamos la coordenada correspondiente en la primera variable
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = coordenadas2[j]
                            part2 = image.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2))
                            colors2 = get_dominant_colors(part2)
                            is_color_in_range_flag2 = False
                            for color in colors2:
                                if color != (255, 255, 255):
                                    is_color_in_range_flag2 = True
                                    break
                            if is_color_in_range_flag2:
                                part2 = part2.convert('L')

                                temp_file_path = f'{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg'
                                with open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as f:
                                    part2.save(f, format='JPEG', quality=100, optimize=True, resolution=300)

                                with Image.open(temp_file_path) as temp_image:
                                    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(temp_image)
                                    temp_image = enhancer.enhance(1.5)
                                    temp_image.save(temp_file_path, quality=100, optimize=True, resolution=300)

                                new_file_name2 = f'{n+1}.{1}{j+1}.png'
                                file_metadata2 = {'name': new_file_name2, 'parents': [destino_id]}
                                with open(temp_file_path, 'rb') as f:
                                    media2 = googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(f.read()), mimetype='image/png', chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)
                                file2 = service.files().create(body=file_metadata2, media_body=media2, fields='id').execute()
                            break
                else:
                    continue
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'Error en la API de Drive: {error}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Ha ocurrido un error inesperado: {e}')
    finally:
        if temp_file_path is not None:  # Verificamos que la variable tenga un valor antes de intentar eliminarla
            os.remove(temp_file_path)  # borramos archivo temporal creado
```

I have tried to change the resolution of the images, thinking that this would solve it, but it has not. I would like all broken images to be recognized by google docs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.